# Align button horizontally in top of frame and table bottom vertically

Tags: scala, swing, scala-swing

I get in trouble with the fact of after clicking on a button : I would like my table is set at bottom of my button but it's not that

I've managed to get it without after clicking a button but without, I've tested many things and nothing.

Here is the code :

```
contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      contents += Button("Top 10 most commun runways latitude") {
        val headers = Array.tabulate(10) {"Col-" + _}.toSeq
        val rowData = Array.tabulate[Any](10, 10) {"" + _ + ":" + _}
        contents += new ScrollPane(new Table(rowData, headers))
      }
      contents += Button("10 highest and lowest number of countries") {
        }

      contents += Button("Type of runways per country") {}
  }
```

What I get
[image: What I get]

What I would like
[image: What I would like]

Comment: The default layout manager of the JFrame should do the job. Add a panel with your buttons to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START. Add the scroll pane with your table to the BorderLayout.CENTER. Read the Swing  tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples of using each layout manager.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it but how I remove a component ?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? If you change the data of the table you can just use the `setModel(...)` method of the table. Or you can replace the component in the scroll pane by using the `setViewportView(...)` method of the scroll pane. If you truly need to remove it then read the Container API for the remove(...) method.